# How to filter by nested attributes in JSONAPI?

Tags: json-api

Assuming we have the following data structure

```
    "data": [
    {
        "type": "node--press",
        "id": "f04eab99-9174-4d00-bbbe-cdf45056660e",
        "attributes": {
            "nid": 130,
            "uuid": "f04eab99-9174-4d00-bbbe-cdf45056660e",
            "title": "TITLE OF NODE",
            "revision_translation_affected": true,
            "path": {
                "alias": "/press/title-of-node",
                "pid": 428,
                "langcode": "es"
            }
...
}
```

The data returned is compliant with JSON API standards, and I have no problem retrieving and processing it, except for the fact that I need to be able to filter the nodes returned by the path pid.

How can I filter my data by path.pid?

I have tried:
- node-press?filter[path][pid]=428
- node-press?filter[path][pid][value]=428

to no avail

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It's not well defined in the filters section of the specification but other parameters such as [include](http://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-includes) describe accessing nested keys with dot-notation. You could try `?filter[path.pid]=428` and parse the filter that way.

Answer (score -1):

```
"field_country": {
                    "data": {
                        "type": "taxonomy_term--country",
                        "id": "818f11ab-dd9d-406b-b1ca-f79491eedd73"
                    }
                }
```

Above structure can be filtered by `?filter[field_country.id]=818f11ab-dd9d-406b-b1ca-f79491eedd73`